# To find $B$ for every $A$: $ABA=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that for every $n \times n$ matrix $A$ there exists a matrix $B$ such that $ABA=A$

Comment: Do you have any thoughts? If you have no idea how to approach a problem like this it's always a good idea to get your hands dirty with a few examples and see what you can come up with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: suppose $A=UV$ is a [rank decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization). We want $UVBUV=ABA=A=UV$. Hence it suffices to find a $B$ such that $VBU=I$.