# Show for every square matrix $A$, there exists square matrix $B$ such that $ABA=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$M_n(F)$ is the set of all $n\times n$ matrices over field $F$. Now assume $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Prove that there exists such $B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ that $ABA=A$.

I've already seen [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4143275/to-find-b-for-every-a-aba-a). I don't know about rank of a matrix and rank decomposition a lot, yet. I read about it a little, but I couldn't figure out how can I find such $B$ that $VBU=I$.

I prefer not using rank decomposition and use other concepts of linear algebra. I tried some examples on small matrices. It's obvious that if $A$ is invertible, then $B=A^{-1}$
gives the answer. But for not invertible matrices I don't know how to construct matrix $B$ or show that it exists.

Some concepts I am somehow aware of:

- row-reduced echelon forms
- matrix elementary operations
- vector space definition and properties, dimension, basis, etc

Any help or hint is immensely valuable to me!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I did read about it but I couldn't solve the problem using it. I know it can be solved without rank decomposition. Anyways, can you give me a hint on how to find $B$ such $VBU=I$, please? I will try to solve the problem using rank decomposition.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Oh so the hint to find $B$ in $VBU=I$ is von Neumann regular rings. Yes?

Comment: Do you know how to use Gaussian elimination to turn a square matrix $A$ into a diagonal matrix with $1$s or $0$s in the diagonal?

Comment: @durianice Yes, I do. Somehow similar to finding RREF of a matrix.

Comment: All the row operations applied to $A$ can be seen as a left multiplication by an invertible matrix $U$ and all the column operations can be seen as a right multiplication by an invertible matrix $V$. Then you get that $UAV=I$, where $I$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal $[1,1,1,\dots,0,0,0]$.

Comment: Then you can follow the wiki article on von Neumann regular ring. That is, if $A=UIV$, then let $B=V^{-1}U^{-1}$. We have $ABA=UIIV=UIV=A$ by direct computation.